# Move From Video View to Scene in Android

Tags: android, andengine

I am using andengine for my app. I am showing video from particular scene using OnAreaTouched method. I have implemented ontouchlistener on video view. I wanted to move to next scene on onTouch method of video view. But i am unable to move to the next scene,even engine.setScene() not working. I am posting my code here for referance.

```
private void videoscreen(){

       setContentView(R.layout.video);

        final VideoView vv=(VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
        String uri = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video1;
        vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uri));
        vv.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        vv.start();

        vv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {


            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                vv.stopPlayback();
                engine.setScene(scene);
                return true;
            }

        });


    } 

protected Scene scene(){
Scene scene=new Scene();
        scene.setBackgroundEnabled(false);
        scene.setTouchAreaBindingEnabled(true);

        mBgTr = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(main.mBg, main.getApplicationContext(), "Common/bg.png", 0, 0);
        slideBg = new Sprite(0, 0, mBgTr);
        scene.attachChild(slideBg);

        return scene;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set the RenderSurfaceView back.
You can either take a look how AndEngine calls `setContentView` and do the same to return the engine (Not recommended), or just create a new activity for the video view (Recommended).